# R simmer package question about get_mon_arrivals

Tags: r, simulation, event-simulation

I'm currently learning how to use the simmer package in R in order to simulate processes.
I'm trying to gather information regarding a simulation I've built, using the get_mon_arrivals function.

I've noticed something weird about running this function - when I run:

```
arrivalData <- get_mon_arrivals(Mall)
arrivalDataOngoing <- get_mon_arrivals(Mall,ongoing=TRUE)
```

I get 2 different tables - just as expected, the first one containing rows for finished customers only, while the second one contains rows for unfinished customers as well, which are the customers that were generated but the simulation ended before they managed to finish the trajectory.

But if I write it the other way around, meaning:

```
arrivalDataOngoing <- get_mon_arrivals(Mall,ongoing=TRUE)
arrivalData <- get_mon_arrivals(Mall)
```

I get the same exact table in both cases. I know it's not something important, but I would really like to understand WHY it does that. I know I can fix it easily by going with the first option, but I am a man who likes to understand what he does.
Thanks alot for the help

Comment: This is a bug. I've just opened an issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/r-simmer/simmer/issues/240

Comment: Hi, the bug doesn't appear to match with my question.
You're stating in the bug that the ongoing adds duplicate rows, but what I'm saying is if you run ongoing=T first, and ongoing=F second, you will receive the data table of ongoing=T in both cases.

Comment: Yes, it does. Try installing the current development version from GitHub and you'll see that this doesn't happen anymore.